# Can I dynamically generate a python function on form submit?

Tags: python, forms, function, for-loop, flask

I am building a web app in Flask for which I would like to generate a new function every time a form is submitted on the client side. Here is what my setup looks like:

I have a form component defined in index.html which sends data to my Flask server through a POST request:

```
    <form method="POST">
    <input name="api" />
    <input name="api" type="submit" />
    </form>
```

On the Flask server, I have defined a static function, "some_plot()", a new version of which I would like to be dynamically auto generated every time the form is submitted. What is happening here is that the user submits an API key in the form submit, and this is used by the function to automatically plot a chart based on the data received from the API. I would like each new function to dynamically be given a new name, such as "some_plot1(), some_plot2(), some_plot3()", etc.

```
def some_plot():

if request.method == 'POST':
    api= request.form['api']
    datasource= fr.series.observations(api)

    plot = figure(y_range=[-15, 20], plot_height=300, sizing_mode='scale_width')
    plot.line(source=datasource, x='date', y='value',  line_width=2)

    script, div = components(plot)
    return script, div
else:
    return 'string'
```

The reason I would like a new function to be dynamically generated on every form submit is because I am rendering the graphs as follows. Every new plot function needs to be listed in the "show_dashboard()" function so that it is rendered on the webpage. You can see below that I manually listed the static "some_plot()" function, but what I would like is for a new function to be created and listed on every form submit. Something like "some_plot()1, some_plot()2, some_plot(3)" etc... Would this be feasible? What may be a good approach to accomplish this?

```
#Render Webpage#
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

    def show_dashboard():
        plots = []
    #Call Graph Function
        plots.append(Urban_Index_Plot())
        plots.append(Real_GDP_Plot())
        if some_plot():
            plots.append(some_plot())

        return render_template('index.html', plots=plots)
```

Comment: Why not just use indexes of your `plots` array? Also, what type does `some_plot()` return?

Comment: I'm using Bokeh to visualize the graphs so the some_plot() function returns an HTML div and JS script generated by Bokeh.

Comment: if you just want to change the name why not using `__name__`?